# Laravel ajax request returns 500

Tags: ajax, laravel

this is JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#add-more-acadimic').on('click', function(){
            $('#add-new-acadimic').modal();
        });

        $('#SaveAcadimic').on('click', function(){

            var name = $('#acadimic').val();
            $.post("{{ route('postInsertAcadimic')}}",{name: name},function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
        });


    });
</script>
```

and this is my route file

```
Route::post('/manage/course/insert_acadimics', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@postInsertAcadimic',
    'as'   => 'postInsertAcadimic'
]);
```

this is controller function

```
public function postInsertAcadimic(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        return response(Academic::create($request->all()));
    }
}
```

and i use csrf token meta tag along with this code in master blade:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}});
```

and this is the console error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/manage/course/insert_acadimics 500 (Internal Server Error) XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/manage/course/insert_acadimics".
```

and this is laravel log error:

```
[2017-08-06 19:32:42] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "name".' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\vendor\symfony\console\Input\ArgvInput.php:181
```

Comment: Are you sure the log entry is caused by your 500 error in question?

Comment: yes i guess so.

Comment: Then why dont you open up ArgvInput.php:181 and see what function is there, do search in your codebase or whole project for that function and determine where its wrongly called... Did you try postman and your API?

Comment: In post method you are passing only name parameter `{name: name}`, so when you are creating Academic, try `Academic::create($request["name"]) ` instead of `Academic::create($request->all())`

Comment: @MIdrees still returns 500

Comment: Try to diagnose error detail. Use `$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/missing.html" ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
  }
});` Look for these variables values. might give some details about real error message.

Comment: I think you should have one more `return` statement, so that even when it isn't an ajax request, the function will still return something.

Comment: i fixed the issue but when i dd the $request i get serialized data how can i get the variable value of it?